# Does odata v4 support aggregation on date values?

Tags: odata, odata-v4

I am looking for an OData query syntax which helps to solve Sum((DateDiff(minute, StartDate, EndDate) which we do in SqlServer. Is it possible to do such things using OData v4?

I tried the aggregate function but not able to use the sum operator on the duration type. Any idea?

Comment: Whilst OData aggregations can be handy, 9 times out of 10 it is faster to implement a Custom _Function_ to do this for you. Is this your API and are you open to a solution that uses a custom function? If so please update your post with more information like the full SQL query your are trying to replicate and some example results. There are many other added benefits to using a _Function_ that can be demonstrated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute a query like that directly in standards compliant v4 service as the built in Aggregates all operate on single fields, for instance there is no support for creating a new *arbitrary* column to project the results into, this is mainly because the new column is undefined. By restricting the specification to only columns that are pre-defined in the resource itself, we can have a strong level of certainty on the structure of the data that will be returned.

If you are the author of the API, there are three common approaches that can achieve a query similar to your request.

1. Define a [Custom Data Aggregate](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs01/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs01.html#_Toc378326320), this is way more involved than is necessary, but it means you could define the aggregate once and use it in many resource queries.

   - *Only research this solution if you truly need to reuse the same aggregate on multiple resources*
2. Define a Custom *Function* to compute the result of all or some elements in your query.

   - Think of a *Function* as similar to a SQL View, it is really just a way of expressing a custom query and custom response object that is associated with a resource.
   - It is common to use *Functions* to apply complex filter conditions that still return the resource that they are bound to, but you can return an entirely different structure of data if you want.
3. Exploit Open Type, this can sometimes be more effort than you expect, but can be managed if there is only a small number of common transformations you want to apply to the resource and project their results as discrete properties in addition to the standard resource definition.

   - In your case you could project `DateDiff(minute, StartDate, EndDate)` into its own discrete column, perhaps called `Minutes` or `Duration`. Then you could `$apply` a simple `SUM` across this new field.

Exposing a custom Function is usually the least effort approach, because you are not constrained by the shape of the result at all, it can be maintained in relative isolation from the main resource, as with Open Types, the useful thing about functions is that the caller can still apply OData aggregates to the result of the Function.

> If the original post is updated with some more detailed code examples, I can elabortate on the function implementation, however in this state I hope this information sets you on the right path.